# Apache commons-io dependency error in build.gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm also facing this issue in Gradle dependency, when i use below method:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File, String with data);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File, String with data, String encoding);
```

The eclipse showing `'method doesn't exist'` error. So I have updated my build.gradle dependency as below:

```
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
```

but this common-io 2.4 version jar is not downloading, I have modified again as below, actually it is getting downloaded and method doesn't exist issue also resloved

```
compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-io:2.4')
```

But now I am getting `"Illegal entry in Gradle Dependencies: D:/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/unresolved dependency - org.apache.commons commons-io 2.4"`

Java version details:

> java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Gradle version details:

> Gradle 2.7 Groovy: 2.3.10 Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013 JVM: 1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23) OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Please try: `compile ('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')`.

Comment: no luck, still same error. if i add compile ('commons-io:commons-io:2.4') getting error at project level and class level. So again I am reverting to compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-io:2.4') and refreshing all dependencies in gradle, now I am getting error only in project level - "Illegal entry in Gradle Dependencies: D:/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/unresolved dependency - org.apache.commons commons-io 2.4"

Comment: Seems like it is an compatibility issue with the Platform version(OS, java). I have used common-io 2.5 as--> compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'. Now the issue is fixed